# Differences between Upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 and a full new installation of 16.04

Tags: upgrade, software-center

1. I upgraded an Ubuntu Studio 15.10 to a 16.04 and it works so fine, with a lot of "old" software I often used and still use.
2. I formatted another PC (same hardware) and I installed Ubuntu Studio 16.04 "from the scratch".
   In this device there is a lot of software I can't download from the "new" Software Center.
   Is there a way to get it?